# where to find epuf format?

Tags: epub, epub3

I want to read a epub  and I know it is zipped.

and I want to ask that where is the format of the epub ?

for example

if should start at .opf and in there is a xml of package

but what is inside package? I want to find the version 2.0 and 3.0 format

Comment: not sure i understand your question, but you'll find the format / mimetype inside the mimetype file at the root of the epub file. You can open the epub archive with any zip programs and navigate inside it to see how it is made. You can also take a look at  https://github.com/IDPF/epub3-samples/tree/main/30 . You can unzip the folders, and then  navigate insides the directories to look at the source or open any book with an ebook reader opening the package.opf or content.opf or any single .opf file standing in each templates/samples. You can also unzip any epub you have and are curiuos about.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I want to develope a epub reading tools so I need to find the all format of it.

Comment: okay, an epub is made of html files stored inside a zip file. you need at first a program that can open the zip file (.epub) and then interpret xml/html files Specification can be find on idf http://idpf.org/epub-older-versions .There is also a suite that your reader should pass : https://github.com/IDPF/epub-testsuite . It should help you to start figure out your needs then also have specific questions ;)

Comment: the suite is good but it seems only has a 3.0 test where is the 2.0 ?

Comment: http://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0_latest.htm  For epub2, you need to yhink like 10 or so years ago : css2 and no html5 ... , If obsolete specification cannot be found anymore, search for old template or even old ebooks that was made 10 years ago . files needed for epub2 is about : http://bbebooksthailand.com/bb-EPUB2-boilerplate.html You can find templates searching with the right keywords. what i found for example https://github.com/javierarce/epub-boilerplate/blob/master/book/OEBPS/content.opf also (keywords: boilerplate epub2 specification) however if you can read an epub3, epub2 will be

Comment: @G-Cyrillus ok so how to give the bounty?

Comment: Oh, that was only comments, it was meant to give you hints from what i found for myself.  I'm not an expert about *epub* . I have similar questions but on the opposite side from your point of view ;) .   It just happens that i'm actually searching for infos too , I'm , for the fun and personnal curiosity, trying to  build a php script (as a plugin for a light CMS)  to build epub3 (Also readable in epub2 readers) , so far it basicly makes a readable epub, with a few errors , i have to dig further in specification, dublin Core and accessibility. If an expert is passing by this post , enlight us.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it is expired and can not give to you sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPUB format can be found on *(at this posting time)*

> EPUB Open Container Format (OCF) 3.2
>
> Final Community Group Specification 08 May 2019

https://www.w3.org/publishing/epub32/epub-ocf.html

and for an older specification,

> Open Packaging Format (OPF) 2.0.1 v1.0.1
>
> Recommended Specification September 4, 2010

http://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0_latest.htm